# PL/SQL FUNCTION ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DOUBLE" when expecting one of the following: (

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

I'm trying to to create this simple PL/SQL function that takes from the user a price value and apply a discount on it to return the price after the discount.
but I keep getting this error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DOUBLE" when expecting one of the
> following: (

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CalculateDiscount (PRICE IN DOUBLE)
RETURN DOUBLE
IS
TOTAL DOUBLE;
BEGIN
SELECT DISCOUNT_ALLOWED FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID = :APP_USER;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN TOTAL := 0;
TOTAL:=PRICE * DISCOUNT_ALLOWED;
TOTAL:=PRICE - TOTAL;
RETURN TOTAL;
END;
```

Comment: i believe replacing DOUBLE with NUMBER will fix your issue

Comment: @Oguen Thank you. but still I'm facing the same error even with NUMBER.

Comment: Ahmed, you are using `DOUBLE` twice: in the `FUNCTION` parameter and as a variable type for `TOTAL`. Since `DOUBLE` as it is is incorrect, you will need to fix it at both places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intended to use `DOUBLE PRECISION`, there is no `DOUBLE` type in Oracle. You could also use `NUMBER`. See more here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58241/ch5.htm#427628